# Passing ArrayList parameter to controller action ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am writing an application wherein I need to send a System.Collections.ArrayList data as a parameter from one controller action to another. 
I am using

```
return RedirectToAction("action1","controller1", new { arrList = arrListInFirstAction});
```

But since the ArrayList goes out of scope in the first action, the parameter in the redirected to action receives a null parameter.

Can someone please help me find an answer to this problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can not send complex types as route parameters. you can, however, use TempData collection to keep that object for one request and on next request it will be automatically removed from collection

```
publci ActionResutl action()
{
     TempData["arr"] = new int[]{1,2,3};
     return RedirectToAction("action1");
}

Public ActionResult action1()
{
    int[] arr = TempData["arr"];
    return View();
}
```

Comment: @Amit That was easy, huh?  =)

Comment: @Pete: Yup, it was pretty easy :)